# replace/replaceAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use replace in order to remove some characters in a 2d array of strings, but I keep incountering an issue:

```
      dataArr[j,k] = dataArr[j,k].replaceAll(mCH, "");
                              ^

TypeError: dataArr[(j , k)].replaceAll is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\magshimim\say-hi-to-sheli-from-me\rafaels-crypto-ninja\thingy\server\index.js:45:35)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

this is the part of my code using the function:

```
for (let j = 0; j < dataArr.length; j++)
{
  for (let k = 0; k < dataArr[j].length; k++)

  {
      dataArr[j][k] = dataArr[j][k].replaceAll('"', "");
      dataArr[j][k] = dataArr[j][k].replaceAll(":", "");
      dataArr[j][k] = dataArr[j][k].replaceAll("I", "");
      dataArr[j][k] = dataArr[j][k].replaceAll("L", "");
      dataArr[j][k] = dataArr[j][k].replaceAll("S", "");
      dataArr[j][k] = dataArr[j][k].replaceAll("}", "");
  }
}
```

Do I need to download anything? maybe there's a problem with my code?

Comment: String.prototype.replaceAll() method was added in ES2021/ES12, are you running an old framework?

Comment: Why did you edit your code so the error doesn't match it anymore (and so my answer doesn't seem to apply)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.replace` function instead of `replaceAll`, if the later is not available.

`"any string".replace(new RegExp("to replace", "g"), "new text")`

This is by using `new RegExp("text to replace", "g")` as a string to search

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you index a 2-dimensional array (well, array of arrays; there are no 2-dimensional arrays in JavaScript).

You're looking for `dataArr[j][k]`, not `dataArr[j,k]`.

`[j, k]` evaluates to just `k` since the comma is parsed as [the comma sequence operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator); `j` is evaluated and thrown away, and `k` is the result. It is then used to index the top-level `dataArr`, and indeed, `replaceAll` is not a method on the arrays nested within.

You could also rewrite this as a double `map` and use a regexp so you don't need to spell out all of those replacements:

```
dataArr = dataArr.map(row => row.map(c => String(c).replace(/[":ILS}]+/g, "")));
```

Comment: fixed that, thanks,everything works out wonderful right now

Comment: Then whatever you have in your `dataArr` is either not a String, or [your environment doesn't support `replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility).

Comment: That was a sneaky edit of your comment... 